# Can't pass an int from button if / else case to media player

Tags: android, if-statement, button, int, media-player

how are you supposed to let the mediaplayer know what it is supposed to play?

`wholeTextPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Lesson1Reading.this, engAu);`

It works fine if I declare the file in the top:

```
MediaPlayer wholeTextPlayer;
private int engAu = R.raw.l1r_en_l10;
Button btn_default_acc_whole;
```

It doesn't work from within a button click if / else statement wherever I try to put it with the following combination:

```
MediaPlayer wholeTextPlayer;
private int engAu;
Button btn_default_acc_whole;
```

The button click:

```
final Button btn_default_acc_whole = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_default_acc_whole);
    btn_default_acc_whole.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (wholeTextPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                wholeTextPlayer.pause();

            } else {
                wholeTextPlayer.start();
                startPlayProgressUpdater();
            }
            setEngAu(R.raw.l1r_en_l10); //this line doesn't want to fit anywhere
        }
    });
```

The setter:

```
public void setEngAu(int engAu) {
        this.engAu = engAu;
    }
```

Of course they are separately placed in the activity, I just copied and pasted the relevant bits from it.

Thanks guys.

Here is the whole code:

'public class Lesson1Grammar extends Activity {

```
private SeekBar seekBar;
MediaPlayer wholeTextPlayer;
private int engAu;
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lesson1grammar);
    WholeDefAccPlayer();

    final RelativeLayout playerScreen = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.playerScreen);

    final ImageButton btn_player_screen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_player_screen);
    btn_player_screen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        //this hides/unhides the part of the layout in which the player is
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (playerScreen.isShown()) {
                playerScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                playerScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });


    final Button btn_default_acc_whole = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_default_acc_whole);
    btn_default_acc_whole.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (wholeTextPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                wholeTextPlayer.pause();
            } else {
                setEngAu(R.raw.default_acc_audio);
                wholeTextPlayer.start();
                startPlayProgressUpdater();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void setEngAu(int engAu) {
    this.engAu = engAu;
}

private void WholeDefAccPlayer() {

    wholeTextPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Lesson1Grammar.this, engAu);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.getTitleOfAccent)).setText(R.string.btn_lesson1reading);

    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setMax(wholeTextPlayer.getDuration());
    seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            seekChange(v);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
    seekBar.setProgress(wholeTextPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

    if (wholeTextPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startPlayProgressUpdater();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
    }
    else wholeTextPlayer.pause();
}

// This is event handler thumb moving event
private void seekChange(View v){
    if(wholeTextPlayer.isPlaying()){
        SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
        wholeTextPlayer.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
    }
}
```

}
'

Comment: Does the setEngAu method used to change playing target?

Comment: I want to use it to tell the media player what to play in the case of that particular button click. Everything is within the same class.

Comment: The media player is always the same. On different button clicks it should play different audio files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your plan is to make the method setEngAu() is the controller as you mentioned in the comment. then you you need to use that method like this

```
public void setEngAu(int enAu)
{
this.EngAu = enAu;
wholeTextPlayer.setDataSource(engAu);
wholeTextPlayer.prepare();
}
```

you need to implement onPrepared listener from the media player
I do not know your classes but I assume where you say something like;

```
wholeTextPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
wholeTextPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
```

here you start the player after it became prepared

```
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player)
    {
       player.start();
    }
```

Remember to you will need to call `wholeTextPlayer.release()` if you do not want the player to hold on that resource anymore( think of it as memory issues - recommended if you check the documentation)

**EDIT** : 
I adjusted your code a little, please take a look and let me know.

```
private SeekBar seekBar;
MediaPlayer wholeTextPlayer;
private int engAu;
 final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lesson1grammar);
        WholeDefAccPlayer();

        final RelativeLayout playerScreen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.playerScreen);

        final ImageButton btn_player_screen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_player_screen);
        btn_player_screen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            //this hides/unhides the part of the layout in which the player is
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                if(playerScreen.isShown())
                {
                    playerScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    playerScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });


        final Button btn_default_acc_whole = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_default_acc_whole);
        btn_default_acc_whole.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {//problem here is
                if(playerState == PlayerState_Playing)
                {
                    wholeTextPlayer.pause();
                    setPlayerState(PlayerState_Paused);
                }
                else if(playerState == PlayerState_Paused)
                {
                    wholeTextPlayer.start();
                    setPlayerState(PlayerState_Playing);
                }
                else
                {
                    setEngAu(R.raw.default_acc_audio);
                    wholeTextPlayer.start();
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                    setPlayerState(PlayerState_Playing);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setEngAu(int engAu)
    {
        this.engAu = engAu;
        if(wholeTextPlayer !=null)
        {//just in case you call this method and player was not initialized yet
            wholeTextPlayer.release();
        }

        setPlayerState(PlayerState_Preparing);
        wholeTextPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, engAu);
    }

    private void WholeDefAccPlayer()
    {
        //this line probably will fail because engAu is not really initialized yet, unless you have default value for it
        wholeTextPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, engAu);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.getTitleOfAccent)).setText(R.string.btn_lesson1reading);

        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        //you can not call getDuration unless the player is prepared, so this might crash you
//        seekBar.setMax(wholeTextPlayer.getDuration());

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b)
            {
                if(playerState != PlayerState_Preparing)
                {//if player state is preparing it means we can not seek yet, player.start() must be called first
                    wholeTextPlayer.seekTo(i);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {

            }
        });
    }

    public void startPlayProgressUpdater()
    {
        if(seekBar.getMax() != wholeTextPlayer.getDuration())
        {//in case you change track later, this will check if the seek bar max value with track duration.
            // if they are not the same, then it will adjust it for you
            seekBar.setMax(wholeTextPlayer.getDuration());
        }

        seekBar.setProgress(wholeTextPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

        if(wholeTextPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
        }
        else wholeTextPlayer.pause();
    }

    // This is event handler thumb moving event
    private void seekChange(View v)
    {
        if(wholeTextPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) v;
            wholeTextPlayer.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
        }
    }

    private final int PlayerState_Preparing = 0;
    private final int PlayerState_Playing = 1;
    private final int PlayerState_Paused = 2;

    private int playerState;
    private void setPlayerState(int state)
    {//this is used to track the player state, because wholeTextPlayer.isPlaying() can return false in many conditions ( too general )
        //you can check in the media player documentation to know more details about this
        playerState = state;
    }
```

Comment: Hi M.Baraka, thanks for the reply. I tried to implement the bits you have provided, but still no luck. Here is the whole code. It should make it easier to solve the problem. There again, if I declare the audio file in the top as private int engAu=R.raw.default_acc_audio the player does everything that it should do. If I try to declare it in the button's if statement, the file doesn't seem to get out of there. Please see the whole code above. Thanks again

Comment: I would say your main issue would be in the if statement where you set the engAu, but you do not really tell the player about the track, and you still ask the player to start.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I tried it. It crashes. The problem seems to be the same. I think it might be around here: "//this line probably will fail because engAu is not really initialized yet, unless you have default value for it" as you said. If I change the "private int engAu;" line to "private int engAu=R.raw.default_acc_audio;" just to see if the player works, it plays the file, so somehow the file is still not getting out of that button click if case to let the wholeTextPlayer know what to play.

Comment: When I start playing the file, the audio is breaking up until I pause it and when I restart it again from that paused point, it plays fine, but the seekbar stops working. Any suggestions there? Many thanks again.

Comment: the breaking up might be your connection is not good enough to buffer it fast, about seekbar, i forgot to add startPlayProgressUpdater(); before wholeTextPlayer.start(); in the onClick for the button. Basically every time you start the player, you need to start updating progress.

Comment: It still didn't work, BUT you pointed me to the right direction and I managed to figure it out. You have given me new ideas, too. There again, without your help it wouldn't have happened. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: I couldn't vote your comment up, because I don't have "15 reputation" yet. Sorry

Comment: you can try to accept the answer itself if possible. glad I could help.